# Does the getting field name via reflection is an expensive operation that should be avoided?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm writing some validation code.

And don't want to declare much constants, so thinking about more dynamic way of how to get a name of properties of a class.

I.e.

```
class User {
   String firstname;
   String lastname;

   getters/setters ....
}
```

Is the access via the

```
User.class.getDeclaredField("firstname").getName();
```

is an expensive operation and I rather go with constants or some other way?

Comment: Define "expensive". Will you do that 5 times, or 5,000,000 times in one run? Does it matter if your program takes 0.5 seconds longer?

Comment: What are you validating? If you can give more context, then you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `User.class.getDeclaredField("firstname").getName();` that will give as output firstname that is the same that the parameter.

```
long init = System.currentTimeMillis();

for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
{
    Field[] fields = User.class.getDeclaredFields();

    for(Field field : fields)
    {
        field.getName();
    }
}

System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-init);
```

That code takes only 500 ms, so in my opinion search between the fields isn't expensive

As suggested I added something in the loop for preventing the VM removing dead code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
long init = System.currentTimeMillis();
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    Field[] fields = User.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.getName().equals("firstname")) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - init);
}
```

Comment: The benchmark doesn't really tell much about reflection performance in a real system, because the VM can eliminate the dead code within the loop (it's not used for anything).

Comment: I added some "logic" and the times are the same (plus 80ms) although it's true that this isn't a real benchmark. 
Thank you, I don't know that the VM can do that :)

Comment: [This article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html) on benchmarking pitfalls is a good read. Some JIT optimizations might also take place in the second version, but it's hard to tell. Anyways, I think your conclusion is valid when it comes to accessing class metadata (field names etc.). However, reflectively creating objects through `getInstance` has a much bigger performance hit.

Comment: Thank you so much for the article, it's very interesting!